# imagejpeg is returning nothing

Tags: php, image, object, jpeg

I have very strange problem with imagejpeg. Take a look at my code:

```
class ImageShow extends PageTemplate{
    public static function Grayscale(){
        $object = Image::CreateObject($_COOKIE["image"]);
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($object);
        imagedestroy($object);
        die();
    }
}
```

So this is the function that i call and this is Image::CreateObject:

```
public static function CreateObject($url){
    $url = "temp/".$url;
    $imgInfo = getimagesize($url);
    switch($imgInfo['mime']){
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $object = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
            //print 'jpeg';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $object = imagecreatefrompng($url);
            //print 'png';
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $object = imagecreatefromgif($url);
            //print 'gif';
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
            break;

    }
    return $object;
}
```

So I get the mime-type right, but when I output the object it shows non-existing image like this one - http://s18.postimg.org/dk4f2ji95/Untitled.png

I think the image object is okay, because when i output it without the content-type header i get a lot of strange symbols :)

Answer (score 0):

Today I learned that if you have ob_start() somewhere before the image creating, you should clean it before the header...

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($object);
imagedestroy($object);
```